# Master project calendar for all Azure DevOps ADO projects and Orgs

Tags: azure-devops

We have multiple ADO projects for the different teams. Client is asking for a master publishing calendar where they can see all project launches in one calendar. Is there a way to get all of this from different projects into one view?

Comment: Can you please let us know what do you mean by `Project Calendar`? Did you encounter any issue when using any built-in feature of Azure DevOps? By the way, have you tried to use the [Delivery Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/add-edit-delivery-plan?view=azure-devops) of Azure Boards, which helps users visualize and manage their work across **teams** and **projects** on a single timeline?

Comment: Oh shoot, I also need to access projects across different ADO orgs. Looks like Delivery Plan can't pull in work items across Orgs or else this would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Thought, the [Delivery Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/add-edit-delivery-plan?view=azure-devops) of Azure Boards, which helps users visualize and manage their work across **teams** and **projects** on a single timeline, I am afraid there is no feature at the moment that enables us to manage Azure Boards across **organizations** in one calendar.

For this, you could create a feature request via: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion . That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate Product Group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.

Still, the feature may not be released in the near future, since the functionality may require different permissions to view and manage work item for users from different organizations.

Comment: I wonder if Power BI can pull tasks across organizations. Do you know?